# Correct nHibernate use for child class references

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

I have an issue where I have the following

```
class Parent{
  public Guid id;
  public List<Child> children = new List<Child>();
}

class Child{
  public int Index;
  public List<GrandChild> grandchildren = new List<GrandChild>();
}

class GrandChild{
  public string GrandChildType;
}
```

Where each generation has it's own set of details (most of the details omitted for simplicity).  I have been struggling for the correct way to generate the xml for the Parent class as I am fairly new to nhibernate and ORM in general.  Ignoring my previously clumsy attempts at doing this I would like to know what I **should** be doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do is to observe the Doc and its examples:

- [6.8. Bidirectional Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional)

Where we can see exactly this scenario. Let's see that adjusted to your needs, for a first level... grandchild will then be the same:

```
<class name="Parent" lazy="true" batch-size="25">
    <id name="Id" column="id"/>
    ....
    <set name="Children" inverse="true" lazy="true"  batch-size="25"
         cascade="all">
        <key column="parentId"/>
        <one-to-many class="Child"/>
    </set>
</class>

<class name="Child">
    <id name="Id" column="id"/>
    ....
    // new property 
    <many-to-one name="Parent" class="Parent" column="parentId"/>

    // similar for grand child
    <set name="GrandChildren" inverse="true" lazy="true"  batch-size="25"
         cascade="all">
        <key column="ChildId"/>
        <one-to-many class="GrandChild"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

IMPORTANT: there are few places to improve *(from ORM tools point of view)* in your C# entities.

1) We MUST use an interface for collections, to allow NHibernate to inject its own (very very smart one) implementation, which does lot of tricks e.g. lazy loading... so instead of `List<Child>` we should use `IList<Child>`
2) We should (almost must) introduce the other end mapping - i.e. Child should have Parent

3) also I'd prefer to map properties (setter could be protected) - just my preference
4) properties must be virtual then

```
class Parent
{
    //public Guid id { get; set; }
    //public List<Child> children = new List<Child>();

    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    // property instead of a field mapping
    public virtual IList<Child> Children {get; set;} 
}

class Child
{
    public virtual int Index{ get; set; }

    // new property 
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<GrandChild> Grandchildren { get; set; }
}
```

That would be the basic mapping. Also try to read more about the in the [doc](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional). If any issues later... do not wait to ask...